# What is the magic behind this update_attributes code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In views/items/edit.erb.html, there is this code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, :label => "tilte" %>
    <%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => "description" %>
    <%= f.association :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :label => "Categories" %>
    <%= f.submit 'submit', class: 'btn bnt-large btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

And in ItemsController, this code:

```
def edit
    @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
    @categories = current_user.categories
end

def update
    @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])

    if @item.update_attributes(item_params) 
        flash[:success] = "updated successfully!
        redirect_to items_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Why just  **@item.update_attributes(item_params)** this line, it can also update association part? There are any official documents describing this? I just want to know more about the magic behind this. I want to know why it work.

Thanks you all.

> I checked the link, seems this magic is from Nested Attributes, but in my model, I didn't have **accepts_nested_attributes_for** line, but it work!!!  Is Rails default to use it? If I selected all the categories, it will update all to database, if I canceled one of them, it will destroyed from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to update the association because you have this line in your Item class

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
```

You can inspect the `item_params` to see exactly what was sent to the ORM

```
if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
  p item_params
  flash[:success = "updated successfully!"
  ...
```

Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods)

Comment: I found the magic is from Active Record Autosave Association.

Answer (score 0):

update_attributes receives a hash as a parameter. Probably, at the end of your code, you have something like:

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:bla, :ble, :bli)
end
```

This defines the parameters your controller will consider valid, when passed to it.
So, having this hash, you send it to your update_attributes, and it works things out.
You could as well pass a hash you made yourself, given the parameters passed are permitted. Something like

```
@items.update_attributes({ bla: "first param", ble: "second param", bli: "third param" })
```

Some more cool information about the method [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes)

Comment: I know it receives a hash as the parameter. I just feel cool why it can work that way, if there any rules describing in the official documents? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just edited my answer with additional documentation. Hope it helps =]

Comment: Seems no contents about it. But still thanks for your answer :)